# React Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘map’)

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing code that stores data about the walks that person do during the week.

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wbn3ms?file=src%2FStepsForm.js

dataList works well in console but in browser there is an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘map’)
at StepsForm (StepsForm.js:84:1)

Also, when I add date it's double date.

It should work this way: https://www.loom.com/share/0159984de8474c7ab090361b3f6b68d4

Could you please help me, what do I do wrong?

Comment: Please include the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setList((prevList) => {
  if (index === -1) {
    prevList.push(newData);
    prevList
      .sort((a, b) => {
        return a.id - b.id;
      })
      .reverse();
  } else {
    prevList[index].distance = String(
      prevList[index].distance * 1 + newData.distance * 1
    );
  }

  return [ ...prevList ];
});
```

add return [...prevList] at the end you were not returning it and it was undefined and was not a array so map error